# Can this problem be treated in purely mathematical way other than the graphical way?

Tags: complex-systems

[Problem Statement:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFW9U.jpg)

[image: problem]

I attempted all the parts.

For part (a), $E_1 = P + R + S$, so $ \dot E_1 = \dot P + \dot R + \dot S$. Plugging these values and rearranging the terms would get the desired expression. From any 3D plotter, we can see that $P+R+S=1$ would give us a plane.

For part (b), when $P, R, S <1$ and $P+R+S=1$, then this is also a plane but this time it is closed in the positive octant. So, the shape is a triangular shape closed plane. If we draw the phase plane, it's quite obvious that it is invariant. But I don't see how to prove that mathematically?

For part (c), (e), (f) and (g), from the following linked picture, the desired result can be obtained. The link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8fAJ.jpg.

For part (d), the proof is similar to part(a). We need to plug in and rearrange and assume that $P+R+S=(P+R+S)^2=1$.

My question is whether there is a detailed method to prove the same result without the help of that picture. Can't we have a purely mathematical treatment of it?

Comment: For those who have a similar problem, I got a hint. I need to use Poincaré–Bendixson theorem here to mathematically prove that result.

Comment: I have entered the image, by using the shift/prtsc of windows 10, which allow to make a .png file using PAINT , that the system here accepts

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem about physics at all, surely mathematics stackexchange would be a better fit.